# Употребление частицы "не" в вопросе

Tags: грамотная-речь, частица-не

Пожалуйста, подскажите, насколько вежлива и грамотна такая постановка вопроса:

***Не*** подашь мне чашку?
**Не** сможешь погулять с ребенком?

Answer (score 2):

"Не подашь" вполне вежливо и употребимо.

Примеры из Нацкопруса:

― Надо же, еще одиннадцати часов нет, и такая жара. Ты **не подашь** мне минералки? ― В холодильнике, если ты хочешь холодную, ― любезно, но сквозь зубы. [Тамара Орлова. Ловушка для ящериц // «Октябрь», 2003]

Да **не подашь ли** мне, старой, водицы испить? [Саша Черный. Солдатские сказки/ Бестелесная команда (1932)]

"Не сможешь погулять с ребенком?" тоже вежливо и грамотно, но я бы сократил эту фразу: "Сможешь погулять с ребенком?" 
Это очень тонкие нюансы, но, как мне кажется, в данном случае "не" и "сможешь" выполняют одну и ту же функцию, а поставленные вместе как бы слегка намекают на невозможность выполнить действие.